# Why can't I get the data when I used hbase CompareOp.valueOf('EQUAL') in scan FILTER to query the rows?

Tags: hbase, nosql

I want to query the rows with hbase `CompareOp.valueOf('EQUAL')` in `scan FILTER` like this, but I can't get the data, and I'm sure there are data matching condition in the hbase.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.CompareFilter
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.SingleColumnValueFilter
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.SubstringComparator
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes

scan 'HBASE_TABLE',
    {COLUMNS => ['INFO:EMAILTYPE'],
    FILTER => SingleColumnValueFilter.new(Bytes.toBytes('EMAILTYPE'),
              CompareOp.valueOf('EQUAL'),Bytes.toBytes('gmail.com'))}
```

Is it because `'gmail.com'` contains a dot/point?